# Parallax image flickering on Safari

Tags: html, css, sass, safari, parallax

I have a problem on Safari when scrolling on a parallax image.
The site works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

I did try to reduce the image size but that did not work.

My css:

```
background-image: url(../images/03-clinical-trials/bg-clinical-trials-01.jpg);
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-bottom: 64px;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

the page link is:
https://www.amramedical.com/clinical-trials

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did the solution below fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the `background-attachment: fixed;` style, which causes a repaint whenever the user scrolls.

One solution is to move the element containing the fixed background image to its own pseudo-element, and use the [`will-change: transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change). Something along these lines:

```
  .left-right-boxes-clinical {
    padding-bottom: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .left-right-boxes-clinical::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/03-clinical-trials/bg-clinical-trials-01.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* This is the important part */
    will-change: transform; 

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , and sorry i did not answer back because i didn't get a notification that my question got an answer. Unfortunately this solution didn't solve my issue.

Comment: The background didnot show anymore,i did as you said and pushed the code to stage link
https://amraab.staging.wpengine.com/clinical-trials

Comment: The `z-index` on the `:before` element is causing the issue. Change it to `0` or remove it, though other elements might need to have a background-color applied or that image will show all the time.

Comment: Or change/remove the `background-color` on the `#content` element.

Comment: that fixed the issue but it did effect the disign of the whole template.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you'll need to make some additional changes to the styles for this to fix to work.